# Find the elements that sum to a given value using R

Tags: r, iteration

I have a data frame it contains `key_var` and `Amount` field as shown below:

Overall Sum of the Amount for the particular key_var should come between 0 to 1 (0-0.99) after removing the particular records/elements, Now I need to identify those removable records and create a 'FLAG' against them (by creating a new var as `FLAG`).
There can be multiple combinations generated but I need only one combination of set to be generated using R.

FYI, If we remove the last 12 records/elements from the below data set then sum matches to 0.25.
This is doing manually now, I need to generate R code to automate the same.

```
df<-structure(list(key_var = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "XYZ_1234", class = "factor"),  Amount = c(8200304.5, 8160830.25, -8035850.35, -7843855.06, -7638726.82, 7635197.95, 6947059.96, -6779376.16, -6659630.59, -6538178.03,  3890858.28, 3727088.57, 3440399.02, 2612664.47, 2147241.37, -1381553.09, -1307455.22, 1253244.05, -1077622.65, 1035065.78, 1020172.5, -1018263.84, 893138.6, -892595.1, -676137.21, 565106.18, -451752.19, -444984.92, -333922.62, -333922.39, 281748.19, -235644.35, -159120.68, 145970.31, 124236.96, 124160.23, -98276.99, -88602.23, -66468.98, 61162.81, 36316.05, 24832.04, 21011.73, 13469.54, -13143.08, -11365.96, 5528.03,3822.78, -3788.55, -1809.79, 995.66, -543.5, 511.52, -18.22, -1.81, 0.96, 0.87, 0.86, 1.66)), .Names = c("key_var", "Amount"), row.names = c(NA, -59L), class = "data.frame")
```

[image]

Thanks,
Vinayak

Answer (score 2):

You can try a "top-down" approach. This will `cumsum` from the beginning and stops when the sum is within the range.

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  mutate(Sum=cumsum(Amount),
  Flag=between(Sum,0,0.99)) %>% 
  filter(c(rep(T, which(Flag)), rep(F,n()-which(Flag))))
    key_var      Amount          Sum  Flag
1  XYZ_1234  8200304.50   8200304.50 FALSE
2  XYZ_1234  8160830.25  16361134.75 FALSE
3  XYZ_1234 -8035850.35   8325284.40 FALSE
4  XYZ_1234 -7843855.06    481429.34 FALSE
5  XYZ_1234 -7638726.82  -7157297.48 FALSE
6  XYZ_1234  7635197.95    477900.47 FALSE
7  XYZ_1234  6947059.96   7424960.43 FALSE
8  XYZ_1234 -6779376.16    645584.27 FALSE
9  XYZ_1234 -6659630.59  -6014046.32 FALSE
10 XYZ_1234 -6538178.03 -12552224.35 FALSE
11 XYZ_1234  3890858.28  -8661366.07 FALSE
12 XYZ_1234  3727088.57  -4934277.50 FALSE
13 XYZ_1234  3440399.02  -1493878.48 FALSE
14 XYZ_1234  2612664.47   1118785.99 FALSE
15 XYZ_1234  2147241.37   3266027.36 FALSE
16 XYZ_1234 -1381553.09   1884474.27 FALSE
17 XYZ_1234 -1307455.22    577019.05 FALSE
18 XYZ_1234  1253244.05   1830263.10 FALSE
19 XYZ_1234  1020172.50   2850435.60 FALSE
20 XYZ_1234 -1018263.84   1832171.76 FALSE
21 XYZ_1234   893138.60   2725310.36 FALSE
22 XYZ_1234  -892595.10   1832715.26 FALSE
23 XYZ_1234  -676137.21   1156578.05 FALSE
24 XYZ_1234   565106.18   1721684.23 FALSE
25 XYZ_1234  -451752.19   1269932.04 FALSE
26 XYZ_1234  -444984.92    824947.12 FALSE
27 XYZ_1234  -333922.62    491024.50 FALSE
28 XYZ_1234  -333922.39    157102.11 FALSE
29 XYZ_1234  -235644.35    -78542.24 FALSE
30 XYZ_1234  -159120.68   -237662.92 FALSE
31 XYZ_1234   145970.31    -91692.61 FALSE
32 XYZ_1234   124236.96     32544.35 FALSE
33 XYZ_1234   124160.23    156704.58 FALSE
34 XYZ_1234   -98276.99     58427.59 FALSE
35 XYZ_1234   -88602.23    -30174.64 FALSE
36 XYZ_1234   -66468.98    -96643.62 FALSE
37 XYZ_1234    61162.81    -35480.81 FALSE
38 XYZ_1234    24832.04    -10648.77 FALSE
39 XYZ_1234    13469.54      2820.77 FALSE
40 XYZ_1234    -3788.55      -967.78 FALSE
41 XYZ_1234      995.66        27.88 FALSE
42 XYZ_1234     -543.50      -515.62 FALSE
43 XYZ_1234      511.52        -4.10 FALSE
44 XYZ_1234        0.96        -3.14 FALSE
45 XYZ_1234        0.87        -2.27 FALSE
46 XYZ_1234        0.86        -1.41 FALSE
47 XYZ_1234        1.66         0.25  TRUE
```

More generalized solution would be to get all combinations from top to bottom. So first rows `1:nrow(df)`, then `2:nrow(df)`, `3:nrow(df)` and so on... The output is a data.frame spezifing the start and end value to subset the data.frame. So `sum(df$Amount[1:47])` as well as the three single values e.g. `sum(df$Amount[44:44])` give you the expected result. Then, you can add a column with `TRUE`/`FALSE`'s.

```
res <- data.frame(A=1:nrow(df), B=nrow(df)) %>% 
  split(.$A) %>% 
  map(~df[.$A:.$B,]) %>% 
  map(~mutate(.,Sum=cumsum(.$Amount),
              Flag=between(Sum,0,0.99))) %>% 
  keep(~any(.$Flag)) %>% 
  map_dbl(~which(.$Flag)[1]) %>% 
  tibble(Start=as.numeric(names(.)), Stop=.)  %>% 
  mutate(Stop= Start + Stop - 1)
res
# A tibble: 4 x 2
Start  Stop
<dbl> <dbl>
1     1    47
2    44    44
3    45    45
4    46    46

# add Flag column of the first match
df %>% 
  rownames_to_column() %>% 
  mutate(Flag=FALSE) %>% 
  mutate(Flag=ifelse(between(as.numeric(rowname), res$Start[1], res$Stop[1]), TRUE, Flag)) %>% 
  head
   key_var   Amount Flag
1 XYZ_1234  8200305 TRUE
2 XYZ_1234  8160830 TRUE
3 XYZ_1234 -8035850 TRUE
4 XYZ_1234 -7843855 TRUE
5 XYZ_1234 -7638727 TRUE
6 XYZ_1234  7635198 TRUE
```

The data

```
df <- structure(list(key_var = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "XYZ_1234", class = "factor"), 
    Amount = c(8200304.5, 8160830.25, -8035850.35, -7843855.06, 
    -7638726.82, 7635197.95, 6947059.96, -6779376.16, -6659630.59, 
    -6538178.03, 3890858.28, 3727088.57, 3440399.02, 2612664.47, 
    2147241.37, -1381553.09, -1307455.22, 1253244.05, 1020172.5, 
    -1018263.84, 893138.6, -892595.1, -676137.21, 565106.18, 
    -451752.19, -444984.92, -333922.62, -333922.39, -235644.35, 
    -159120.68, 145970.31, 124236.96, 124160.23, -98276.99, -88602.23, 
    -66468.98, 61162.81, 24832.04, 13469.54, -3788.55, 995.66, 
    -543.5, 511.52, 0.96, 0.87, 0.86, 1.66, -1077622.65, 1035065.78, 
    281748.19, 36316.05, 21011.73, -13143.08, -11365.96, 5528.03, 
    3822.78, -1809.79, -18.22, -1.81)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-59L), .Names = c("key_var", "Amount"))
```

Comment: You could also `cumsum(Flag)` and `filter(... > 0)`

Comment: @Jimbou : Thanks for your quick response and valuable time.

I need code itself identify the no. of records for each set of key_var and Flag the removable records.

Overall Sum of the Amount for the particular key_var should come between 0 to 1 (0-0.99) after removing the particular records/elements, Now I need to identify those removable records and create a 'FLAG' against them. There can be multiple combinations generated but I need only one combination of set to be generated using R.

Comment: @ Let's say one unique key has 60 records and overall sum of the amount say 20k. Now my target is to make overall sum of the amount between 0 to 1. So I need to identify the records which can be dropped so that it makes to reach my target ( 0 -1). Just need a flag against removable records out of 60 records.

There can be multiple combinations to make it out, but need atleast one combination of set that can identify the flags for removable records so that the overall sum of the amount matches between 0 to 1.

Now currently people are identifying this manually using trial and error basis.

Comment: @Jimbou : Can we generalized the code? Meaning I don't know how many records a particular key_var has? So code has to identify the no.of records a key_var has and loop them accordingly. Instead of writing A: nrow(df) , B: nrow(df), etc.....Is it doable?

Comment: @Jimbou : I was facing below error when I execute the code :
"Error: Result 1 is not a length 1 atomic vector"

Comment: @Jimbou: I have re ordered the data in the questions, Can you please  use the above posted dataset "df" and try to get the similar results?

I was facing some error ""Error: Result 1 is not a length 1 atomic vector" when I execute the solution 2 generalised code.

I have posted the image file it contains the output dataset, if possible pls post the code again.

Awaiting for your response.

Answer (score 0):

I assumed you wanted to sample part of the "Amount" values until the condition was met the sum of the Amount values would be between 0 and 1. I took this approach, although it can take a lot of time:

```
dput(df)
structure(list(key_var = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "XYZ_1234", class = "factor"), 
Amount = c(8200304.5, 8160830.25, -8035850.35, -7843855.06, 
-7638726.82, 7635197.95, 6947059.96, -6779376.16, -6659630.59, 
-6538178.03, 3890858.28, 3727088.57, 3440399.02, 2612664.47, 
2147241.37, -1381553.09, -1307455.22, 1253244.05, 1020172.5, 
-1018263.84, 893138.6, -892595.1, -676137.21, 565106.18, 
-451752.19, -444984.92, -333922.62, -333922.39, -235644.35, 
-159120.68, 145970.31, 124236.96, 124160.23, -98276.99, -88602.23, 
-66468.98, 61162.81, 24832.04, 13469.54, -3788.55, 995.66, 
-543.5, 511.52, 0.96, 0.87, 0.86, 1.66, -1077622.65, 1035065.78, 
281748.19, 36316.05, 21011.73, -13143.08, -11365.96, 5528.03, 
3822.78, -1809.79, -18.22, -1.81)), .Names = c("key_var", 
"Amount"), row.names = c(NA, -59L), class = "data.frame")

continueloop = TRUE
while(continueloop){
  x <- sample(df$Amount, sample(2:dim(df)[1], 1))
  if(sum(x) > 0 & sum(x) < 1){ 
  continueloop = FALSE
 }
}

df$FLAG <- ifelse(df$Amount %in% x, TRUE, FALSE)
```

You can replace the 2 in the second sample() function to specify the minimum number of times FLAG should be TRUE. If it is 1, it could sample just one row where Amount is between 0 and 1.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable time and quick response to answer the questions.

Overall Sum of the Amount for the particular key_var should come between 0 to 1 after removing the particular records/elements, Now I need to identify those removable records and create a 'FLAG' against them. There can be multiple combinations generated but I need only one combination of set to be generated using R.

FYI, If we remove the last 12 records/elements from the below data set then overall sum matches to 0.25.
This is doing manually now, I need to generate R code to automate the same.